# How to setup log4net so that it works on a wcf service?

Tags: c#, log4net

I'm working with a solution on visual studio 2008, .net framework 3.5, windows 7. I've created a log4net library that writes to a txt file and want to use it on several projects on my solution and also on a wcf service that's in the same solution which is running locally from visual studio.

I start the program from a console application on the solution. And the console app calls the other projects and those projects use the log4net. At this level in the workflow the log is writing fine. The problem comes when the wcf service is called. The wcf service uses the log, but log4net doesn't write to the file.

**On the console project I have this:**

On the AssemblyInfo.cs:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```

On the App.config I have the log4net configuration.

On Program.cs, on the Main method I have:

```
LogManager.GetLogger("Initialise log4net from the current assembly attributes");
```

**On the WCF Service I have this:**

The same on the AssemblyInfo.cs as the console project.

Same on Web.config as the App.config on the console project.

On the constructor of the Service1.svc I have:

```
LogManager.GetLogger("Initialise log4net from the current assembly attributes");
```

**This is how my App.config and Web.Config loos like:**

inside     the configSections tag:

```
 <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,Log4net"/>
```

and inside the main configuration tag:

```
 <log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG"/>
      <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
    </root>
    <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >
      <file value="C:\test3.txt"/>
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%d [%t] %-5p %c %m%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
  </log4net>
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: I never managed to get my WCF services to use assembly attributes, in the end I gave up and just used `XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(...)`

Comment: @stuartd You are saying I should remove the log4net part on the web.config of the service and leave the part on the AssemblyInfo.cs on the service. I did that change but still the service does not write to the file.

Comment: No, I never managed to get my WCF services to load log4net via assembly attributes, so I used the XmlConfigurator instead to configure logging. I didn't spend too much time on it as I wanted to get logging working and move on. Does `LogManager.GetRepository().Configured` return true after your call to GetLogger?

Comment: @stuartd Ok, so the XmlConfigurator would be done in c# code behind........ **LogManager.GetRepository().Configured** returns false.

Comment: @stuartd do you have an example of the XmlConfigurator so I can configure the logging?

Comment: Probably you should change AssemblyInfo code as below: [assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4net.xml", Watch = true)] , and configure log4net in a different file. For more details, you can check my comment below (https://stackoverflow.com/a/58709425/9294131)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Do you have an example of the XmlConfigurator so I can configure the logging?*

```
var logpath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/web.config");
var fileInfo = new FileInfo(logpath);

if (fileInfo.Exists == false)
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Can't locate the web.config file");
}

log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(fileInfo);
```

Note that only the overload of the ConfigureAndWatch method which takes a FileInfo can watch an app.config or web.config as it reads the .config file directly instead of using System.Configuration (which once it reads the file cannot re-read it).

The documentation explains this [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html#dot-config).

Edit by @pyram: because both projects are logging to the same file it was necessary to add this line to the appender config of both projects:

```
<lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
```

Comment: I have placed your answer code in the service constructor before the call to the GetLogger method. I can see that **LogManager.GetRepository().Configured** returns true, but still the service doesn't write to the file. I have placed my config in my question.

Comment: Config looks OK. Are you making a log call?

Comment: a call to the GetLogger method?.....yes, in my service constructor I have placed your code, and right after that I've made a call to the log like this **LogManager.GetLogger("Initialise log4net from the current assembly attributes");**

Comment: @pyram You don't need to initialise the assembly attributes as you're using the XmlConfigurator but you do need to call one of the logging methods on the logger to actually log anything - eg `LogManager.GetLogger("test").Debug("test logging");`

Comment: Yes I'm calling the logging methods, but nothing gets written.

Comment: Does the file get created?

Comment: the file gets created but is not created by the service. Remember the starting point of my solution is the console app and then the service. So, the console app creates the file and writes to it, but after that when the service tries to write to the file, it doesn't work.

Comment: If both apps are logging to the same file, you'll need to add `<lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />` to the appender config for both services.

Comment: I added that line, but no results.

Comment: Try logging to a different file

Comment: I tried logging to a different file and it creates the file and writes to it without problems.

Comment: I had forgot to add `<lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />` to the console project. I added it now and the service is writing fine to the same file. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Log4Net Configuration in WCF should be as below:

1. Install Log4net nugget package in your project

> This will add log4net package to references, double check.

2. Add the following line in AssemblyInfo.cs

   `[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4net.xml", Watch = true)]`
3. Create log4net.xml in application root, and add configurations for logging, as below:
   [image]
4. Add log property in service to use it in every method:

   `private static readonly log4net.ILog _log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(
       System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);`
5. Use _log as follow:

   `catch (System.Exception ex) _log.Error(ex);`